# Load FileName, last modified date and file contents to a table using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

in ADF, how do you capture the contents of multiple files with same structure to a database table along with its filename and lastmodified date ?

I have 4 files in a directory with the same structure and I need to capture the contents of the file to a sql table along with respective file names and Last modified date as shown below

[image]

Comment: they are CSV files, I need to process the data every time from these files and based on the last modified date I need to do some calculations

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of GetMeta data activity and Foreach and copy activity.

1. Use GetMetaData Activity to get the list of files
2. Use Foreach to iterate over that list
3. with foreach use getmetadata activity on individual file to get the last modifieddt
4. Use Copy activity to copy that details in table

Ref link: stackoverflow.com/questions/70853149/azure-synapse-analytics-adding-source-file-name-as-column-value-in-sink-in-pipel